# Why does std::forward converts lvalue and rvalue to rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

I suppose I am confused with `std::forward`.
My function which uses `std::forward` is following, but it is much simplified and modified to make explanation easily.

```
// This is an example code to explain my question simply.
template <typename Element>
void add(Element&& element) {
    static std::vector vec;
    vec.push_back(std::forward<Element>(element));
}
```

I tried two case with the function above; Case 1 lvalue argument and Case 2 rvalue argument.

Case 1: lvalue argument

```
auto some_class = SomeClass();
add(some_class);
```

Case 2: rvalue argument

```
add(SomeClass());
```

In debugger both cases passes the same following parts, `std::forward` part and `std::vector` part.

`std::forward` part:

```
template<typename _Tp>
constexpr _Tp&&
forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
{ return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t); }
```

`std::vector` part:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  void
  push_back(value_type&& __x)
  { emplace_back(std::move(__x)); }
```

It seems `std::forward` part converts both cases to rvalue reference, `&&`, because it uses `static_cast<_Tp&&>`. And `std::vector` is treated both elements as rvalue reference because it uses `std::move()`.

I have expected augment of Case 1 is lvalue because it has its own name and Case 2 is rvalue because it does not have its own name. 
I also have expected `std::forward` converts Case 1 to lvalue reference and Case 2 to rvalue reference.
 Are my understandings of lvalue, rvalue and `std::forward` correct? If so, why `std::forward` converts both as rvalue reference, `&&`.

If I made a mistake, I am sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why `std::forward` converts both as rvalue reference

It shouldn't. According to the rule of [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), when an lvalue is passed to `add`, the template type argument `Element` will be deduced as `SomeClass&`. Then `std::forward<SomeClass&>(element)` will be invoked, and the instantiation of `std::forward` would be

```
// before reference collapsing
constexpr SomeClass& &&
forward(SomeClass& __t) noexcept
{ return static_cast<SomeClass& &&>(__t); }
```

and

```
// after reference collapsing
constexpr SomeClass&
forward(SomeClass& __t) noexcept
{ return static_cast<SomeClass&>(__t); }
```

So for the 1st case, `std::forward` will return an lvalue. An lvalue-reference returned from function is an lvalue.

BTW, for the 2nd case, the templare argument `Element` will be deduced as `SomeClass`, then you can do the same inference as above, at last the instantiation of `std::forward` would be

```
constexpr SomeClass&&
forward(SomeClass& __t) noexcept
{ return static_cast<SomeClass&&>(__t); }
```

An rvalue-reference returned from funtion is an rvalue.

---

The result you got seems weird, for the 1st case, `std::vector::push_back(const T&)` should be invoked. (I tried a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9HuuEF8GxeIZC35f))

Comment: Thank you for answering in detail. I agree my question above is weird. I read my code again. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

The part that you're missing is reference collapsing. When passing in an lvalue, it will have type `T&` (or `const T&`) for some `T`. If you add this into the `forward` template, you get:

```
return static_cast<T& &&>(__t);
```

Due to reference collapsing rules, this collapses down to `T&`.

Effective Modern C++ covers this in Item 28. Basically:

- Lvalues of type T are deduced as `T&`.
- Rvalues of type T are deduced as `T`.

With this, and the reference collapsing rules above, hopefully you can understand how `std::forward` works.

Comment: thank you for telling me the reference. I will read it again.